# How do I translate the following "for /f" command from cmd for an equivalent command in Linux centos 6,64?

Tags: linux, centos, cmd.exe, wget, save-as

How could I translate the following CMD command to a command in linux centos 6,64?

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %i in (links.txt) do wget -O "%j" "%i"
```

PS: links.txt is a file with 2 columns separated by tab, one with the link and the other with the name on how to be saved the file.

Thanks

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hint: - [for](https://ss64.com/bash/for.html) - Expand words, and execute commands once for each member in the resultant list, with name bound to the current member.

Comment: Dear David, hello, thanks for your answer. I have tried the formula 

for /f "tokens=1*" %i in (links.txt) do wget -O "%j" "%i"

In linux though its not working. Only cmd, I didnt find any post where it says on how to do this in linux.

Could you help how to do? If so thank you very much

Comment: So you want to translate that Windows command to an equivalent Linux command? If that's the case, please state it clearly in the question ([edit] it), because currently it's hard to understand what you're trying to do. It's not a "formula", a "command" is the proper term. Finally, DavidPostill's comment is right. You have to show us your attempts and tell where you're stuck. We can help you, but not do your job.

Comment: Dear gronostaj, hello, have edited the question as per your suggestion. I said exactly what I am doing, which is the command I explicited above in cmd. The post is for asking some help if someone would know howto translate this command into linux centos 6,64, because in linux is not working, and didnt find any tutorial about how to do this so far. Thanks

Comment: DavidPostill gave you a link to an explanation of the `for` loop in bash, Linux's most common shell. Have you read it? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `awk`

Even if it is possible to read from a file and compose the command you want in a cycle there is a command you may find more cosy: `awk`.

If the filename are all without spaces you can use this simple syntax to create the command you want then redirect (`|`) this output to a shell (`sh`) that will execute it.
With `$1` you take the 1st column, with `$2` the second and so on...

```
awk '{print "wget -O "$2,$1}' links.txt | sh
```

If there are spaces in the names you have to do some gym more:

```
awk -F $'\t' '{print "wget -O\""$2"\" " $1}' links.txt | sh
```

Here you must specify that the field separator `-F` is the tab (`-F $'\t'`)
and you have to print the `"` before and after the file name. Since you are inside a string you need to escape<sup>[[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3834857/3569208)]</sup> them
`echo "Those are double quote\""`.

**Try this command without the redirection** (so without the  `| sh` ) to have the possibility to control the output, then execute it when you are sure...

Use `man awk` to have further help.

Comment: Hello Hastur, thank you very much, works perfect, Thanks

Comment: Ypu can add a different path after the `-O\"` and before the `"`... or you can tun the script from the final directory. BTW __Warning:__ for the unix filenames is allowed the use of _not common_ characters as the newline one, that may make some mess in your plan. Search for _why is not safe/auspicable to parse ls output_ to know more...

Comment: Hello @Hastur, thanks for the former explanation. If inside the file I only have only 1 column with link (so not 2 columns), and want wget to save file with same name as the column 1, how could I update this command for that? `awk '{print "wget -O "$2,$1}' links.txt | sh` ? I have tried to simply delete the `$2,` but it didnt work. Thank you very much

Comment: @Joao Usually `awk '{print "wget \"$1\" "}' links.txt | /bin/sh` should work... and save the file with the original filename. Note that the option `-O ` is to specify the output name... `man` could be a good friend (in this case `man wget`). `:-)` But it is an overkill... see what happens with `wget -i links.txt`. Again `man` is __really a good friend !__ `:-)`

Comment: Hi @Joao  1st: When you have your own question it is better to post as a new question instead that to ask in the comment (more space and it can be useful for other too). 2nd: The error depends from what do you have inside the file `:-)` and in the question you can add some line of the file to give it as example. 3rd: `man` is the help under Linux. 4th:See some example about how it works `awk` (`gawk`): it composes strings line by line, inserting text from the input in some places (`$1` the `1st` column, `$2`the 2nd... so `...wget -O /outputfolder/"$1".txt",$1` to add .txt in that place.

Comment: Hello @Hastur, thanks a lot, it gave error here, also read the man but couldnt fina  a solution. So have deleted my new comments here which didnt arrive to  solution, so can be able do new post as you suggested. Thanks